# Select attribute using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute

I am using python to select every 1000 attributes in the attribute table. For example, 1:1000, 1001:2000, and so on. How can I write this as a for loop?

Answer (score 4):

The python range function lets you choose a step size:

```
>>> list(range(1,10001,1000))
[1, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001, 6001, 7001, 8001, 9001]
```

So loop over that and select attributes from `N` to `N+1000`:

```
for N in range(1, NMAX, 1000):
  clear_selection()
  for I in range(1000):
    select_attribute(N+I)
  # now we've got 1000 selected features
  do_whatever_with_selection()
  # now loop back, add 1000 to N and select the next 1000
# all done
```

I've put dummy functions for Arcmap's attribute selection functions, this should give you direction for how to select blocks of 1000 in a Python loop.

Comment: Note that IDs for shapefiles start at zero, and file geodatabase IDs, while generated consecutively, are not renumbered after a feature is deleted, so this might generate "at most 1000 features."

Comment: You don't need extra loop when using BETWEEN statement.

Answer (score 3):

List all object ids, then iterate over these and select:

```
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\featureclass'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr')

oids = [oid[0] for oid in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'OID@')]
oidfield = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName()

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for grp in chunker(oids, 1000): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks
    sql = """{0} IN{1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='lyr', field=oidfield), tuple(grp))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='lyr', where_clause=sql)
    #'lyr' is now a layer with a selection
```